# React hooks not triggering on react 18

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-18

I got an app that I'm trying to upgrade.

React v17 => v18,
Next v12 => v13

After the migration react hooks are not working. Below I'm pasting simplified code (I'm not sure where to look from that point)

```
const App: FC<AppProps> = (props) => {
  console.log('xxxxxx1')
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('xxxxxx2')
    }, [])
  console.log('xxxxxx3')
  return (
            <title>
              Test
            </title>
  );
};
```

It gives output

```
xxxxxx1
xxxxxx3
```

Comment: This is weird. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Nope, zero errors in the terminal or browser console.

Comment: Ok, removing build folder helped. Probably some conflict during version upgrade